# Orca behaviour when it reads a text containing words in different language from the main one

Tags: accessibility, internationalization, text-to-speech, orca

I am a totally beginner with screen readers and accessibility tools.

I have installed [Orca Screen Reader](https://help.gnome.org/users/orca/stable/) on my Kubuntu 20.04. I am Italian, so Orca by default is configured with the Italian language.

The strange thing of Orca is that if a text contains a non Italian word, Orca read its as if it's Italian, the result is very confusing.

For example:

> Annulla il filtro pushbutton

Orca pronounces the word *"pushbutton"* as if is an Italian word.

Is there a way to make Orca dynamically detect that a word is in a different language from the main language and make it pronounce that particular word with the correct language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kubuntu 22.04 ships a very old version of Orca (3.36.2), it seems that this is the cause of the problem:

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/orca/-/issues/266